# Is there a html to rich-text npm package for contentful

Tags: node.js, npm, contentful

I'm trying to migrate content out of one system (Drupal to be specific) into Contentful.

When pulling content out of Drupal, it is formatted in HTML. Putting content into Contentful, it looks like it needs to be in a specific JSON format.

Using NPM package `contentful-cli` with command `contentful space import --content-file import.json`

I know there is `@contentful/rich-text-html-render` but I'm looking for the reverse. Or if there's another strategy that anyone know about to import html into Contentful programmatically...

Answer (score 5):

I have create a basic NPM package `contentful-html-rich-text-converter` to do this if anyone else runs across this issue. (It is a work in progress, feel free to contribute)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/contentful-html-rich-text-converter

Comment: this is really old, outdated and doesn't work

Comment: Really old, yes, its from 2019.. You will see many answers in stack overflow that are old as its a historical thread. Outdated and doesn't work, not really... package has been maintained over the years with contributions from others.

Welcome to SO

Answer (score 3):

I used [turndown](https://github.com/domchristie/turndown) to convert to markdown first and then I used @contentful/rich-text-from-markdown to make it to rich text.
It seems to work fine so far.

Comment: can you share an example?