# Converting HTML to Contentful RichText

Tags: python, richtextbox, contentful

Im trying to find a way to convert HTML to RichText (preferably in python)
seems like there is only the other way around, using [rich-text-renderer](https://github.com/contentful/rich-text-renderer.py)

After seeing there was no real solution provided inside contentful repo, and definitely not in Python, I tried to use this nmp package called [contentful-html-rich-text-converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/contentful-html-rich-text-converter) which sounded very promising, but unfortunately this package does not support many HTML tags (for example div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after seeing there is not a close solution in python, I saw [this stackoverflow ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62022004/12042016) that got closed long time ago and decided to write REST api in js, to use in my python project for this use-case:

```
const { richTextFromMarkdown } = require('@contentful/rich-text-from-markdown');
var TurndownService = require('turndown')

var turndownService = new TurndownService()
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.post('/html-to-rich-text', async (req, res) => {
  console.log("body", req.body)
  var markdown = turndownService.turndown(req.body.html)
  const richText = await richTextFromMarkdown(markdown)
  console.log("resp", richText)
  res.send(richText);
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`HTML to RichText server listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

I hope someone in the future will find this useful :)